# how to include $vbulletin class or api into an external php file?

Tags: php, vbulletin

I'm writing an external plugin for vbulletin 4.x version.

If vbulletin installed in the 'root/' folder and my external php file is in the 'root/my-plugin/index.php', what should I include() ?

how to access `$vbulletin` in this file?

```
    $userid = $vbulletin->userinfo[userid];
    $query = $vbulletin->db...;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes , you have to require `global.php` from the forum root folder

your plugin `index.php` :

```
$curdir = getcwd ();
chdir('../');
require_once('../global.php');
chdir ($curdir);

$userid = $vbulletin->userinfo[userid];
$query = $vbulletin->db...;
```